# Cannot access class 'kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have recently started writing a spring boot application in Kotlin. I intend to use Kotlin Coroutines. I have added all the required dependencies in my Gradle file but the IDE keeps showing the following error:

```
Cannot access class 'kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Here is the sample code that I have written:

```
fun createThread(): MyThread {
    GlobalScope.async {
        openApiService.createThread()
    }.await()

}
```

Also, following is the my Gradle file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.21"
}

group = "<mypackage>"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    implementation("com.aallam.openai:openai-client:3.6.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-java:2.3.2")
    implementation("com.theokanning.openai-gpt3-java:service:0.18.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.7.3")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: what IDE are you using? If intellij, try the "invalidate cache and restart" button. You could also maybe try to clear your m2 and gradle cache.

Comment: This worked @Alex. Thanks a lot. Can you please post this as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the correct imports (and it looks like you do), this can be caused by a cache issue.

If you are using Intellij, you might want to "invalidate cache and restart". You can find that in the *File* menu. Here is a [link to the official page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html).

Another thing to try is to delete your maven cache from the `/.m2/repository` folder. If the folder is not in the default location, it can be found with the following command:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout
```

If using gradle, you can also remove that cache from the `/.gradle/caches/` folder.